# When naming an organic molecule - which group has the highest priority: methyl or methylidene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I have been tasked with naming Myrcene. (see image below)

[image]

Which of the following names is correct?

**7-methyl-3-methylidene-oct-1,6-diene**

or

**3-methylidene-7-methyl-oct-1,6-diene**

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Where would the two terms appear in a dictionary?

Comment: Priorities of substitutents need to be considered only while numbering the chain. When naming it after you've numbered it properly, the different substitutents need to be arranged in alphabetical order. Thus the first name is correct, since methyl comes before methylidene in alphabetical order.

Comment: I wanted to figure it out for myself and specifically avoid looking up its name.


Why is it that methyl comes before methylidene in alphabetical order?- I mean, don't they consist of the same 6 first letters?

Comment: @Patrick — This is a convention so we can determine the alphabetical order for any two words; so "methyl" alone comes before any "methyl" followed by any character.

Comment: (Also note that no one is correct. There are 2 issues. Excessive dash between the last substituent and the parent chain name. And missing vowel beween oct- (locants) -diene.)